# Maximum number of controllers Unity3D can handle

Tags: unity, input, xbox-controller

I've been trying to find out the maximum amount of xbox controller Unity3D can handle on one editor. I know through networking, Unity is capable of having as many people as your hardware can handle. But I want to avoid networking as much as possible.

Thus, on a single computer, and in a single screen (think Bomberman and Super Smash Brothers) how many xbox controllers can Unity3D support?

I have done work in XNA and remember that only being capable of support 4, but for the life of me, I can't find any information that tells me how many Unity can support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the answer is 11 different controllers Unity can handle straight out of the box. If you wish to add more, you need to write your own plug in.